# I have a table in the DB called schedule with 2 TIME one is openHour and the other is closeHour

Tags: php, html

What I need to do is to display a range of hours in a page using php and html

I need the range to be located inside of a "select" located in the .tpl but I don't want to do 23 "option" for every hour "select" and 59 "option" for the minute select, for the 7 days,
that will be like 2 selects in every day with one select with 23 options and the other with 59 options.

I already have the connection to the database, I only want to display the hours in a "select" and the minutes in another "select".

What I want is to do a schedule for open business and close business selecting this in every single day not for the whole week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I do it. I have 2 functions.

```
//function to create Hour drop down
function hourDropDown($hour, $day, $type){
    echo "\n<select name=\"" . $day . "_" . $type . "_hour\">\n";
    $selected[$hour] = ' selected="selected"';

    for($i=0;$i <= 23; $i++) {
        if ($i < 10) {$i= 0 . $i;}
        $sel = (isset($selected[$i])) ? $selected[$i] : "";
        echo "  <option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n\n";
}

//function to create Minute drop down
function minuteDropDown($minute, $day, $type){
    echo "\n<select name=\"" . $day . "_" . $type . "_minute\">\n";
    $selected[$minute] = ' selected="selected"';

    for($i=0;$i <= 59; $i++) {
        if ($i < 10) {$i= 0 . $i;}
        $sel = (isset($selected[$i])) ? $selected[$i] : "";
        echo "  <option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n\n";
}
```

Then you can call the functions-

```
echo hourDropDown('08', 'monday', 'open');
echo minuteDropDown ('00', 'monday', 'open');

echo hourDropDown('18', 'monday', 'close');
echo minuteDropDown ('30', 'monday', 'close');

....

echo hourDropDown('09', 'friday', 'open');
echo minuteDropDown ('15', 'friday', 'open');

echo hourDropDown('20', 'friday', 'close');
echo minuteDropDown ('45', 'friday', 'close');
```